# finding general solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A point that I don't understand. The solution says The fact that $y=cos2x$ is one solution tells us that $r^2+4$ is a factor of characteristic polynomial. How come  $r^2+4$ is figured out?

Find the general solution of
$$6y^{''''} + 5y^{'''} + 25y^{''} + 20y^{'} + 4y = 0; y = cos2x$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the derivative operator. If $p$ is a polynomial, then let $p(D)$ be the polynomial with '$x$' replaced by $D$.

Note that the lowest degree monic polynomial $q$ that satisfies $q(D) y = 0$ for
$y(t) = \cos (2t)$ is $q(x) = x^2+4$.

The differential equation is given by $p(D)y = 0$ for a 4th degree polynomial $p$. Hence we can write $p = m \cdot q + r$ for a polynomial $m$ and
the remainder polynomial $r$. If $r \neq 0$ then it has degree strictly less
than $q$.

Since $p(D)y=0$ and $q(D)y = 0$, we must have $r(D) y = 0$, and since if $r \neq 0$, then the
degree of $r$ is $<2$, which is a contradiction. Hence $r = 0$ and
we have $q \mid p$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(2x)$ being a solution means $2i$ and $-2i$ are solutions of the characteristic/auxiliary equation. That means $r-2i$ and $r+2i$ both divide into the characteristic polynomial without remainder, and so does their product. $(r-2i)(r+2i)=r^2 + 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. Then for any $a\in \mathbb{C}$, we have $P(D)(\exp(ax))=P(a)\exp(ax)$. Hence as $\displaystyle 2\cos(2x)=\exp(2ix)+\exp(-2ix)$, we have  $\displaystyle 2P(D)(\cos(2x))=P(2i)\exp(2ix)+P(-2i)\exp(-2ix)=0$ for all $x$. Put $x=0$ and $x=\pi/4$, we get $P(2i)=P(-2i)=0$, hence $(r-2i)(r+2i)=r^2+4$ divide $P$.